# Hibernated error embedding object with primary key

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a @MappedSuperclass called Place which has variables called uniqueId and name.  I also have Country class and City class that extends the Place class.  The City class (@Embeddable) has a variable called mayor and the Country class (@Entity) has a variable called president.  The Country class has two embedded object called capital_city and largest_city.  When I persist the Country object, I get Hibernate error stating country_id (renamed from uniqueId using @AttributeOverride) does not have default value.  The insert statement actually did not have a value for country_id.  When I looked at the create statement, it had defined largest_city_id as the primary key...  I do not understand why Hibernate behave this way.  I need to have country_id as the primary key, and simply embed the two City objects.  The codes are below.

```
// Place class
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Place  {  

    private String uniqueId;
    private String name;

    @Id
    public String getUniqueId() {
        return uniqueId;
    }

    public void setUniqueId(String uniqueId) {
        this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
    }

    @Column(nullable=true, unique=false)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

// Country class
@Entity
@AttributeOverride (name="uniqueId", column=@Column(name="country_id"))
public class Country extends Place {
    private City capitalCity;
    private City largestCity;
    private String president = "";

    public Country() { }
    public Country(String id, String name, City capital, City largest, String prez) {
        this.setUniqueId(id);
        this.setName(name);
        capitalCity = capital;
        largestCity = largest;
        president = prez;
    }

    public String getPresident() {
        return president;
    }

    public void setPresident(String president) {
        this.president = president;
    }

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides ({
        @AttributeOverride (name="uniqueId", column=@Column(name="capital_city_id")),
        @AttributeOverride (name="name", column=@Column(name="capital_city_name")),
        @AttributeOverride (name="mayor", column=@Column(name="capital_city_mayor"))
    })
    public City getCapitalCity() {
        return capitalCity;
    }

    public void setCapitalCity(City capitalCity) {
        this.capitalCity = capitalCity;
    }

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides ({
        @AttributeOverride (name="uniqueId", column=@Column(name="largest_city_id")),
        @AttributeOverride (name="name", column=@Column(name="largest_city_name")),
        @AttributeOverride (name="mayor", column=@Column(name="largest_city_mayor"))
    })
    public City getLargestCity() {
        return largestCity;
    }

    public void setLargestCity(City largestCity) {
        this.largestCity = largestCity;
    }
}

// City class
@Embeddable
public class City extends Place {

    private String mayor;

    public City() {}
    public City(String m, String id, String name) {
        mayor = m;
        this.setUniqueId(id);
        this.setName(name);
    }

    public String getMayor() {
        return mayor;
    }

    public void setMayor(String mayor) {
        this.mayor = mayor;
    }
}

// Main
import test.City;
import test.Country;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        City capital = new City("Tom Smith","1010","Fairview");
        City largest = new City("Jo Somebody","2010","Crestfall");

        Country country = new Country("USA","United States", 
                                       capital, largest, "George Jefferson");

        AnnotationConfiguration cfg = new AnnotationConfiguration();
        Session session = cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(country);
        t.commit();
        session.close();
    }
}

// Bibernate Create SQL codes
Hibernate: drop table if exists Country
Hibernate: create table Country (country_id varchar(255) not null, name varchar(255), 
           capital_city_id varchar(255) not null, capital_city_mayor varchar(255), 
           capital_city_name varchar(255), largest_city_id varchar(255) not null, 
           largest_city_mayor varchar(255), largest_city_name varchar(255), 
           president varchar(255), primary key (largest_city_id))
Hibernate: insert into Country (name, capital_city_mayor, capital_city_name, 
           largest_city_mayor, largest_city_name, president, largest_city_id) values 
           (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Notice the primary key is largest city_id, NOT country_id.

```
// Hibernate error message
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'country_id' doesn't have a default value
```

PLEASE HELP!!!  I'm adding Hibernate notation to an existing codebase, so I do not have much freedom to modify the code.  Hopefully, this can be accomplished through right Hibernate annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a `@MappedSuperclass`s can only be extended by `@Entity`s, not `@Embeddable`s. [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html) says

> Designates a class whose mapping information is applied to the **entities** that inherit from it.

Anyway, I think the issue is when you `@Embed` the `City` in `Country` you are also embedding a second `@Id` attribute. You have an `@Id` attribute inherited by `Country` from `Place` and also an `@Id` attribute coming from the embedded `City`. You basically have 2 `uniqueIds` for a `Country`. Maybe instead of having `Place` be a `@MappedAttribute`, have it be an interface without any JPA annotations:

```
public interface Place  {  
    String getUniqueId();
    void setUniqueId(String uniqueId);
    String getName();
    setName(String name);
}
```

You get the benefits of polymorphism, without the hassle of figuring out the correct JPA mapping or having to [ab]use `@AttributeOverride`